# How to create a repetitive image pattern programmatically?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I want to create the following image patterns using Python.
[image]
For clarity: these are two separate image sequences (one on the top row, one on the bottom row).
They are related to each other as they are projected areas of stacked tetrahedra.
In a 3D environment it looks as follows:

[image]
Note that these 3D object are not scaled such that the total object dimension remains the same. This is the case with the projected areas shown above.
The four level structure (not shown) would have an additional 10 cells on top.
The total amount of cells `C` at level `n` is:

```
C = (n^3 + 3*n^2 + 2*n)/6
```

Now I'm creating the patterns by hand (make 3D object, render out projected area, repeat) but this is very tedious and not feasible for more subdivisions.

I managed to create a single polygon with the following code, but I can't figure out how to loop this such that the total edge length stays the same, but the polygon gets subdivided in the way visualised above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

el = 1
dfv = 1/np.sqrt(3)*el
dfe = 1/(2*np.sqrt(3))*el
vertices1 = [(0,0),(0.5*el,-dfe),(0,dfv),(-0.5*el,-dfe)]
vertices2 = [(0.5*el,-dfe),(0,dfv),(-0.5*el,-dfe)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.add_patch(Polygon(vertices1, closed=True, fill=True))
ax1.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax1.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.add_patch(Polygon(vertices2, closed=True, fill=True))
ax2.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax2.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]
I used matplotlib and the included Polygon patch, but I'm not sure if that is the most optimal method.
Also the orientation of the polygon or the color is of no importance.

Comment: How are these figures going to look like in the next step:-)? Where did you take these images from?

Comment: Fair questions. @pajton I've edited my question to include more details, I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper class:

```
class Custom_Polygon(object):
    """docstring for Polygon"""
    def __init__(self, verts):
        self.verticies = np.array(verts)
        self.dims = self.verticies.shape[1]

    def scale(self, scaleFactor):
        scaleMatrix = np.zeros((self.dims, self.dims))
        np.fill_diagonal(scaleMatrix, scaleFactor)
        self.verticies = np.dot(self.verticies, scaleMatrix)

    def scale_with_orgin(self, scaleFactor, origin):
        origin = origin.copy()
        self.translate([-i for i in origin])
        self.scale(scaleFactor)
        self.translate([i for i in origin])

    def translate(self, shiftBy):
        self.verticies += shiftBy

    def get_width(self):
        x_min = self.verticies[:,0].min()
        x_max = self.verticies[:,0].max()
        return abs(x_max - x_min)


    def get_height(self):
        y_min = self.verticies[:,1].min()
        y_max = self.verticies[:,1].max()
        return abs(y_max - y_min)
```

Made a helper class for scaling and translating the polygon around to make the pattern. And wrote the algorithm for drawing the first pattern. Should not be hard to make a similar algorithm for drawing the second pattern.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

def makeFirstPattern(ax, d, verticies, scale=True):
    Pn = Custom_Polygon(verticies)
    direction = 1 
    divisions = d
    if scale: Pn.scale_with_orgin(2.0/(divisions+1), Pn.verticies[-1])
    for i in range(divisions, 0, -2):
        for _ in range(i):
            ax.add_patch(Polygon(Pn.verticies, closed=True, fill=True, ec='none'))
            Pn.translate([direction * Pn.get_width()/2, 0])
        direction *= -1
        Pn.translate([direction * Pn.get_width(), Pn.get_height()])

el = 1
dfv = 1/np.sqrt(3)*el
dfe = 1/(2*np.sqrt(3))*el
vertices1 = [(0,0),(0.5*el,-dfe),(0,dfv),(-0.5*el,-dfe)]
vertices2 = [(0.5*el,-dfe),(0,dfv),(-0.5*el,-dfe)]


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

makeFirstPattern(ax1, 7, vertices2)

ax1.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax1.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For first pattern you can use this code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

nrows = 5
pat = np.array([[0,0],[0.5,np.sqrt(0.75)],[-0.5,np.sqrt(0.75)]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for base in range(nrows):
    npat = 2*base + 1
    for col in np.linspace(-base/2, base/2, npat):
        pp = Polygon(pat + np.array([col, base*v]), fc='k', ec='none')
        ax.add_patch(pp)

ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works almost. However, the dimensions of the total pattern should remain the same regardless of the amount of division. Now setting `nrows=5` gives a max height of ~4.5, but `nrows=1` gives a height of ~0.9. It should be the same (arbitrary) height though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using matplotlib I'd offer a solution using **SVGs**, where your script only prints out the respective SVG commands.

*Note: The SVG header created is missing same definitions, that's why the resulting image can not be handled by some programs. Inkscape though can open it without problems and save it again.*

#### Defining the polygon in SVG

The solution is describe is based in the "arrow" example you showed, i.e. the lower one.
I coded the arrow as a **SVG path** with four points p0,p1,p2 and p3, where p0 is the upper tip, p1 is the lower right edge, p3 is the lower left one and p2 is the point underneath the tip. Every point has an x and y coordinate (p0x,p0y...).

*Note: SVG coordinates unlike mathematical ones increases from left to right (x) and top-down (y), so the origin is the top-left corner.*

The path is stored as string with the points being varibale. The final string is created using python's `str.format()` method.

#### Code

```
# width of the complete picture
width=600
# height of the complete picture
height=600
# desired recursion depth (>=1)
n=5
# "shape factor" of the arrow (=(p1y-p2y)/(p2y-p0y))
# a=0 would result in a triangle
a=0.3
def create_arrows(n, depth=1, width=600, height=600, refx=None, refy=None):
    global a
    if refx==None or refy==None:
        # the first polygon instances defines it's reference point
        # following instances are given a reference point by the caller
        refx = (width - width/n)/2
        refy = 0
    if depth==1:
        # the first polygon instance defines the size of all instancens
        width=width/n
        height=height/n
    # the SVG definition of the polygon
    polyg = r'<path d="M{p0x} {p0y} L{p1x} {p1y} L{p2x} {p2y} L{p3x} {p3y} Z" />'
    points = {"p0x":refx+width/2, "p0y":refy, "p1x":refx+width, "p1y":refy+height, "p2x":refx+width/2, "p2y":refy+(1-a)*height, "p3x":refx, "p3y":refy+height}
    # create the requested polygon
    polygons = [polyg.format(**points)]
    # if maximum recursion depth not reached call method recursively
    if depth<n:
        polygons.extend(myfunction(n, depth+1, width=width, height=height, refy=refy+(1-a)*height, refx=refx)) # down shifted
        polygons.extend(myfunction(n, depth+1, width=width, height=height, refy=refy+height, refx=refx-width/2)) # bottom left
        polygons.extend(myfunction(n, depth+1, width=width, height=height, refy=refy+height, refx=refx+width/2)) #bottom right
    return(polygons)
print('<svg height="{height}" width="{width}">'.format(width=width, height=height))
# converting the list to a set is necessary since some polygons can be created by multiple recursion paths
print('\n'.join(set(create_arrows(4,width=width,height=height))))
print('</svg>')
```

#### Explanation

The arrows are created in a **recursive** fashion, i.e. you start with the top arrow. The dimensions of the arrows are `width/n` and `height/n`, where `n` is the desired recursion level (n>=1). The examples you showed would be `n=1`, `n=2`, and `n=3`. The below explained recursion pattern was empirically derived and is not directly based on your 3D example.

*n=1*: In level `n=1` you're done after creating the top arrow.

*n=2*: In level `n=2` this TOP arrow creates another three, one right below and each left and right below, respectively. The tips (p0) of these three arrows are at p2, p3 and p1 of the original arrow, respectively. You're done.

*n=3*: Repeat the above procedure for every arrow created in level `n=2` and so on.

Below please find an example for level `n=6`.
For the triangles, your upper example, this idea can easily be adapted. You just have to change the polygon path and recursion pattern.
Btw. a rotated version of your trianlges are created using the given script with `a=0`. So if you're lazy just use that and turn the resulting SVG in inkscape.

[image: imgage created using above script at level n=6]

Comment: The shape factor is slightly off, making the arrow a little more "pointy" but thanks for the code. I'll try this and see how it goes.

Comment: Just change the parameter `a`. I didn't know the exact shape. Hope this works for you!